# Warning: file_get_contents : failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in simple_html_dom.php on line 82

Tags: php

I’ve been trying to access this particular REST service from a PHP page I’ve created on our server. I narrowed the problem down to these two lines. So my PHP page looks like this:

```
$websiteUrl = "https://www.doofootball.com/";
    $dom = file_get_html($websiteUrl);
    var_dump($dom);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rDXA.png)

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem with simple_html_dom. Suddenly it didn't work any longer without passing a context variable. I don't recall where I found this solution but it has been working for quite some time now. Just try this please and let me know whether this resolves your problem.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
//        'http' => array(
//            'follow_location' => false
//        ),
        'ssl' => array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    )
);
$websiteUrl = "https://www.doofootball.com/";
$dom = file_get_html($websiteUrl, false, $context);
```

file_get_html expects these parameters:

```
function file_get_html(
    $url,
    $use_include_path = false,
    $context = null,
    $offset = 0,
    $maxLen = -1,
    $lowercase = true,
    $forceTagsClosed = true,
    $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET,
    $stripRN = true,
    $defaultBRText = DEFAULT_BR_TEXT,
    $defaultSpanText = DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
```

Don't remember why I commented out the lines with "follow_location" ... You'll figure it out. Good luck!